# Select multiple rows as one in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have records in few rows, but need to get them all into one with query.

Here it is:

[image: http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/7808/captn.png]

[**LARGE IMAGE LINK**](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/7808/captn.png)

Comment: @Strawberry +1 on `normalization`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  MAX(rbr) maxRBR,
        id, date,
        MAX(pr1) maxPr1,
        MAX(pr2) maxPr2,
        ....
FROM tableName
GROUP BY id, date
```

Comment: This will select max value for that column, what if I have 2 or more and in same column, and I need last one?

Comment: max will return one value which is the highest among the group, try it.

Comment: I don't need max, I need last ( highest with rbr)

Comment: Yeah, if you need to be more specific about which of the multiple values you want to select, you'll have to be more specific about exactly how you'd choose that value. Max dat field? Last inserted? We'd need a more detailed example.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, dat, MAX(pr1) pr1, MAX(pr2) pr2, ...
FROM table
GROUP BY id, dat
```

Answer (score 2):

For each field which you want to coalesce non-null values you can use this:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    date,
    COALESCE(field1),
    COALESCE(field2)
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY 
    id
```